# Need right direction for reload application by action

Tags: uiviewcontroller

My scenario is a UIView Controller displays different subview programmatically... Like a game board. Now I'm in a incredible situation:

I can't find a way to reload application after the game is finish!? What I would like to do is after terminate scenario clic on IBAction for star new game. My doubt is about ViewDidLoad or call Main.

Answer (score 0):

try moving your code  from viewDidLoad into a new function like -(void)startGame or -(void)refreshViews: and call that function whenever you want to reload your view. even in viewDidLoad you can load your view using this function.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[self startGame];


}
```

remember if you are creating allocating and add some of your subviews outside this function then they will remain visible untill and unless yu remove them from superView before calling startGame.

Comment: in IBAction also call this method.

Comment: hi and thanks iVishal. in my function i will create temporary view while accomplished labels and images. ten load all in[self.view addSubview: imgView];
this is a runtime and cycle dead after 90 runs.

Comment: in IBAction i use "self.view= NULL;
    self.view=[UIView init]; but crash. Any idea

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code:

```
(IBAction)newGame:(id)sender{


    UIView *parent = self.view.superview;
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.view = nil; // unloads the view
    [parent addSubview:self.view];


}
```